# Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Deployment

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Is it a requirement to have [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6610) run on the web server in order to have users view asp.net pages (built with VS2010 SP1) that reference Microsoft **ReportViewer** controls?

I was hoping that if I referenced the dlls in the web project listed in this [MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx), that I would avoid having to run the redistributable package on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to have the redistributable installed on the web server.  Just set the copy local property for the report viewer dll references to true.

See the following article.  It discusses deploying to an Azure environment, but the same idea holds for deploying to a web server without the redistributable package.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430128.aspx

Comment: After adding references to both dlls, and setting the local copy to true, I still receive the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel,...". I confirmed that both the webforms and common dll are in the bin folder.

Comment: See the following thread.  It discusses copying the dll for ProcessingObjectModel from the GAC on your local dev machine to the bin folder of your project.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vsreportcontrols/thread/cdf81c32-ac7c-491f-add7-d1c0c6c746eb

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to install redistributable package on web server as you are sure to have included all of the file related to report viewers.

As you are using report viewer 2010 to show ssrs report so, you should include following dlls in GAC :

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel

For furthur information ,how to use report viewer 2010 and changes need to done in web.config  for using report viewer 2010 ,see following post:http://ivarunsingh.blogspot.com/2011/12/report-viewer-2010.html